# Adding CheckBox in Android at the end of the line in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, checkbox

i have such Linear Layout:

```
    <!-- First column in row with image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bild"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <!-- Second column in row with data -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#464f58"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/numberOfLeaflet"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Third column with checkBox -->
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that this checkBox is not visible.
When i change and give this checkbox before ImageView then I can see this checkBox.

Do you have any idea why I cant see this checkBox in the 3 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second column is set to fill_parent width.  So the last checkbox doesn't fit and is put in the same row, but off the side of the screen.  Easiest way to fix this would be to make that 2nd column not be fill_parent, or to make both it and the checkbox be fill_parent and use weights to make them split the space.  The other thing you can do is to make the outer layout a RelativeLayout so you can set the second column to be layout_leftOf the checkbox and make the checkbox alignParentRight=true.